# Out Of Memory Exception when downloading a video file

Tags: c#, memorystream

We currently download video(s) from Twilio, once the video has been downloaded we save the video in `AWS S3`.  However when deploying to production I'm currently getting:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

When trying to download the video(s),

I've checked the video(s) sizes within Twilio and they're relatively small, 172,912kb

I've upgraded the instances on S3 to large as I assumed that would be an issue as before they we're small.

however the issue still persists, the code block that it fails on is as follows:

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"{resource.Url}/Media");
 request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_twilioOptions.ApiKey + ":" + _twilioOptions.ApiSecret)));
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

 var responseBody = (request.GetResponseAsync().Result).GetResponseStream();

 byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[8192];
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 int read;
 while ((read = responseBody.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length)) > 0)
 {
    ms.Write(tempBuffer, 0, read);
 }

 var result = ms;
    
 var fileName = $"Conversations/{conversationId}/Video-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMdd-hhmmss}-{compositionSid}.{resource.Format}";
 var uploadedFile = await _fileUploader.UploadFile(result, fileName, _s3Options.SecureBucket, "video/mp4");
```

Can anyone recommend a solution / fix for this?

Comment: The file is _already_ in a stream (`GetResponseStream`). Why do you want to copy it to a **new** stream (the `MemoryStream`)?

Comment: Chunk your memory. it'll consume less memory area.

Comment: @Arphile What does that mean?

Comment: Did you try my suggestions @CodeRatchet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically you shouldn't have a problem downloading a ~170MB file into memory all at once on a **S3** (`7GB RAM` plan).  However, you are **not** *disposing* or closing any of your resources.  Depending on the surrounding code this could well be the problem with unmanaged resources not being freed up and could result in out of memory over a period of time.

Now we could make explicit calls to `Close()` or `Dispose()` but its easier to just encase the relevant code in `using()` blocks like so:

```
 
 byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[8192];
 using (var responseBody = (request.GetResponseAsync().Result).GetResponseStream()) 
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) // <------- using block, will call Dispose() 
 {
     int read;
     while ((read = responseBody.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length)) > 0)
     {
        ms.Write(tempBuffer, 0, read);
     }

     var result = ms;
    
     var fileName = $"Conversations/{conversationId}/Video-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMdd-hhmmss}-{compositionSid}.{resource.Format}";
     var uploadedFile = await _fileUploader.UploadFile(result, fileName, 
                                                      _s3Options.SecureBucket, "video/mp4");
}
```

Your code is similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream?view=netcore-3.1) MSDN example however you will note the use of `Close()`.

[Tell me more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream?view=netcore-3.1)

Thanks to mjwills for spotting the `responseBody` can be plonked in a `using()` block too, saving an explicit `Close`.

### Going forward

Even with these fixes, you might want to utilise the best practice of streaming resources rather than loading all at once, particularly if there isn't a requirement to load it all into memory at one time.  Simply create a read stream to the source and a write stream for the target.  Then it is simply a matter of reading and writing blocks at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Well as you might have already guessed, it is a bad idea to keep the whole video in memory if it is large.

Even though 180mb does not seem like much, it still needs a coherent memory region for that in the LOH. You might be better with some approach of writing blockwise to disk. For Performance enhancing and to avoid memory fragmentation in the LOH, you could also use `RecyclableMemoryStream` by the way, but that does nothing for your current system.

Generally you should avoid this design. Either save to disk (with memory buffering) and trust in the filesystem cache for small files, or try to directly feed the downstream into the upstream.

Comment: _"Even though 180mb does not seem like much"_ - As the OP said, he is using a _"[S3](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/)"_ serivce plan which includes `7GB` of RAM

Comment: But it is about having a large enough non fragmented blob of memory...